# Why does this auto array adjuster not work?

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I am working on a new project, and its basically you add two lists and you have a target i just want to add the lists; `list1` & `list2` togather and i have a target; `target` so the i want to predict/configure `list2` until i get the result i want aka `target`.

My code:

```
def random_funct(list1,list2,target):
  def __logic__():
    lists_of_lists = [list1, list2]
    out_sum = [sum(x) for x in zip(*lists_of_lists)]
    out = 0
    
    for i in out_sum:
      out+=int(i)
    
    return(out)
  
  while True:
    my_logic = __logic__()
    if my_logic > target:
      for i in range(len(list2)):
        list2[int(i)]+= 1

    elif my_logic < target:
      for i in range(len(list2)):
        list2[int(i)]-= 1
    
    elif my_logic == target:
      print('algorithm settled on '+str(list2))
      break


if __name__ == '__main__':
  random_funct([2,1],[2,1],5)
```

Comment: The desired output is configured `list2` or a new `list2` that, if you added `list1` with `list2`
you will get the target.

Comment: What would be the expected output for the call `random_funct([2,1],[2,1],5)`?

Comment: @trincot The expected output would be a configured list2, configured in the sense that it will give the target aka `5`

Comment: Yes, but be specific, what would it be for this particular call?

Comment: its going to give an array

Comment: Yes, I get that, but *which* array for *this* call? Can you please explicitly list the values that will be in that array, and explain why those, and not others?

Comment: i believe the values should be `[1,1]`

Comment: OK, but why? Why not [0,2] or [2,0], or [-1, 3]? What is the logic you are trying to implement?

Comment: @trincot logic is just adding 2 lists together. And adding the values in the list together (RETURNS A NUMBER/FLOAT). when you got the number/float you check if the `target` number is bigger or smaller than the number/float we got. and it adjusts one of the list for my case i want to adjust `list2` from my code

Comment: I mean, what is the logic for choosing which value in list2 to adapt? Can you tell why it should be [1,1] and not [2,0]? What is the logic behind that choice? And why not [0,2] or [-1,3] or [3,-1] or any of the billions of other possibilities to reach the target?

Comment: @trincot
the reason that the array is `[1,1]` is cause we are adding 1 to the value or removing 1 to the value. The value being the contents in the list, and the way i figure out whether to add or not to add to my array/list is a `if & elif` statement. in a while loop. i hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, but with the same reasoning one can remove 1 from the second value of the list. What is the logic here? Should subtraction always happen from the *first* value? Is that the logic? Please explain why the other options I mentioned are not valid answers...

Comment: there is no logic behind adding to the second value.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I will leave you to it.

Comment: Thx for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you confused the `<` and `>` signs...

Use this instead:

```
def random_funct(list1,list2,target):
  def __logic__():
    lists_of_lists = [list1, list2]
    out_sum = [sum(x) for x in zip(*lists_of_lists)]
    out = 0

    for i in out_sum:
      out+=int(i)

    return out

while True:
  my_logic = __logic__()
  if my_logic > target:
      list2[0]-= 1

  elif my_logic < target:
      list2[0]+= 1

  elif my_logic == target:
      print('algorithm settled on '+ str(list2))
      break
```

Now you just modify the first item in your list2.
I think it gets the job done.